# uint32_t as datatype for map key

Tags: c++, ip-address, hash, stdmap

My question is, if i use **uint32_t** as data type for the key in **std::map** will it create a huge structure with indexes for each of the 2^32 combinations? Basically I want to generate a couple of 32-bit numbers each of which should be unique. I have the numbers but I am wondering what structure/technique to use to keep them in memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will only create entries that you insert. 
If you only have a small number (you mention a couple) it might be faster to put them in a vector and do a linear search. If it's more than a small number a map will be faster of course.

Comment: If it's a small number, the performance of either is probably too small to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

No, a map only allocates space for actual keys used, not the entire key space.  That would be bad otherwise.